# Scala case class with escaped field name throws error during Spark Catalyst code generation

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

I have a case class with escaped field names such as:

```
case class Buyer(`52_week`: String, `26_week`: String,... other fields)
```

Then I create an instance of this class and pass to Spark DataFrame like:

```
val expected = spark.createDataFrame(sc.parallelize(List(buyer1, buyer2)))
```

When I try to save it:

```
expected.write.mode(SaveMode.Append).format("hive").partitionBy("load_date").saveAsTable(tableName)
```

I get the following exception:

```
Caused by: org.codehaus.commons.compiler.CompileException: File 'generated.java', Line 476, Column 15: failed to compile: org.codehaus.commons.compiler.CompileException: File 'generated.java', Line 476, Column 15: Expression "funcResult15 = value65" is not a type
```

where line 476 is:

```
/* 475 */           Object funcResult15 = null;
/* 476 */           funcResult15 = value65.52_week();
```

So it appears that I need to somehow tell Catalyst codegen to escape these fields.

Is there a way to do it or at least some workaround for the issue ?

I'm using Apache Spark 2.2.0.

Comment: What does stick you to such field names in your case class?

Comment: @GoodDok well, that code was written before me

Comment: were you able to manage this problem somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did is converted Buyer class to Tuple and with explicitly saying which column names to use.

In other words I got around code generation by choosing a different path.

Code snippet looks something as follows:

```
val expected = spark.createDataFrame(sc.parallelize(List(buyer1, buyer2).map(b => Brand.unapply(b).get))).toDF(extractFieldNames[Buyer]:_*)
```

where extractFieldNames is:

```
def extractFieldNames[T<:Product](implicit m: Manifest[T]): Array[String] =
    m.erasure.getDeclaredFields.map(_.getName)
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to make a different `case class` with a constructor building an object out of the old one:

```scala
case class BuyerRenamed(week_52: String, week_26: String,... other fields)
object BuyerRenamed {
  def apply(buyer: Buyer): BuyerRenamed = {
    BuyerRenamed(buyer.`52_week`, buyer.`26_week`, ...)
  }
}
```

Then use the new case class with dataframes, that would resolve the problems with Catalyst, since the fields will be named like `value65.week_52()`, which is an appropriate naming for a method.
Maybe you'll want to add implicit conversion to make the code cleaner.

In a long run, I recommend you to refactor the existing code to get rid of such naming, it may lead to all kinds of sudden errors, especially when you are somehow connected with  automatic code generation.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the answer, because I have a Hive table with column named like 52_week, and if will have a case class with name week_52, how they will match during insertion of BuyerRenamed ?

Comment: Well, if Hive schema is also stable, there's an option to rename the fields back before saving them like `df.select(col("week_52").as("\`52_week\`"), other columns ...)`.